Click on YouTube button inside iframe using YouTube iFrame API
I have a YouTube playlist displayed inside an iframe on a webpage & want to automate clicking on the playlist's 'index button' when the page loads so that the list of videos in the playlist is displayed.
I can see that the button which displays the playlist doesn't have an ID but does have the class ytp-playlist-menu-button & an aria-owns="ytp-id-22"(which I think is equivalent to an ID?).
When I originally posted this question I was shown this StackOverflow Question that references the YouTube Iframe API in its answer.
Having read through the YouTube iframe API documentation I've constructed a javascript based on its explanation. However, although the document explains how to excute various events like 'play the video', 'set the volume' etc, I can't see any guidance as to how I can click on a button (to display the playlist).
I have included the script I've written below & presume that the part I need to change is event.target.playVideo(); at the bottom to something like event.target.triggerButton('ytp-playlist-menu-button'); or event.target.triggerButton('ytp-id-22');
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
  //    after the API code downloads.
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      playerVars: {
        'playsinline': 1
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
     event.target.playVideo();
  }

You can view the actual page I'm working on where the YouTube playlist is embedded here
Any help would be much appreciated.
